# Unable to capture API data with multiple user inputs with Python/PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm working on a python script which pulls TV episode information down from themoviedb.org.

I have a for loop which should gather all the episodes that are entered in to the GUI InputText field I created with PySimpleGUI. When I enter multiple episodes, for instance 1,2,3 it says the script has completed but nothing happens.

Here is the code which sets up the Input Fields, the Season and Directory fields are working as expected.

```
layout = [[sg.Text("Hello, please select the Show, Season, Episodes, and Directory.")]
        ,[sg.Text('Season:'), sg.InputText('', size=(10, 1), key='input_season')]
        ,[sg.Text('Episodes:'), sg.InputText('', size=(10, 1), key='input_episode')]
        ,[sg.Column(file_list_column)]
        ,[sg.Button("OK")]]
```

Here is the code where I am picking up the values from those input fields.

```
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # End program if user closes window or
    # presses the OK button

    if event == "OK" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        Season_Number = values['input_season']
        Episode_Number = values['input_episode'].split(',')
        Episode_String = str(Episode_Number)
        file_location = values['FOLDER']
        break

window.close()
```

Lastly, here is the loop for each episode.

```
episode_list = [Episode_String]
for episode in episode_list:
    text = get_data(API_key, TV_ID, Season_Number, episode)
    if text == "error":
        break
    write_file(text)
```

Within the code I have some print statements and when I print that Episode_String variable it shows the following ['1', '2'], if I copy and paste that over the [Episode_String] in the code above then the script runs for both episodes no problem.

My issue appears to be with getting the values from that input box and allowing the loop to parse through each of those episodes individually.

*After submitting I had the thought to add a print of the API URL that is getting sent when I have multiple episodes and it appears that is the issue, as this is the URL that is getting sent. I've removed my API key from the URL, [https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/114505/season/1/episode/%5B'1',%20'2'%5D?api_key=zzz&language=en-US&append_to_response=images](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/114505/season/1/episode/%5B%271%27,%20%272%27%5D?api_key=zzz&language=en-US&append_to_response=images)
It seems like the current code doesn't work with even one episode as it adds data to the URL

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you input `1,2` in field `input_episode`, then

```py
Episode_Number = '1,2'.split(',')       # ['1', '2']     - two-string list
Episode_String = str(Episode_Number)    # "['1', '2']"   - str
episode_list = [Episode_String]         # ["['1', '2']"] - one-string list
```

So you cannot use `[Episode_String]`, just `Episode_Number`

```py
episode_list = Episode_Number
```

For `print("['1', '2']")`, you will get output as `['1', '2']`, it doesn't meat it is a list.

Comment: If I remove that episode string and set it to episode number, then I get a TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str.

That was why I originally added that episode_string variable, but I understand what you were saying about the output of it.


I would assume that comes from the API query since it is strings getting concatenated together.
  
`query='https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/'+TV_ID+'/season/'+Season_Number+'/episode/'+Episode_Number+'?api_key='+API_key+'&language=en-US&append_to_response=images'
  response=requests.get(query)`

Comment: `...+'/episode/'+episode+...`, not concatenate list `Episode_Number`

Comment: That made total sense. I changed that and removed the brackets around Episode_Number on the episode_list variable and that worked. Thank you so much for your help!